# UWP - Image size is not changed in metdata after resizing

Tags: uwp, image-resizing

I managed to resize a picture in UWP app and when I'm opening image it has the correct size, but the issue is that the image metadata still shows the original image size value.

Does the image metadata has to be changed at some point?

Many thanks for your help!

Here's a code I'm using:

```
 private async Task ResizeFile(StorageFile resizedFile, StorageFile sourceFile, int width, int height)
 {
        var imageStream = await sourceFile.OpenReadAsync();

        var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(imageStream);

        // get original picture size
        int originalWidth = (int)decoder.PixelWidth;
        int originalHeight = (int)decoder.PixelHeight;

        // calculate aspect ratio
        var ratioX = (float)width / (float)originalWidth;
        var ratioY = (float)height / (float)originalHeight;

        int newWidth = width;
        int newHeight = height;

        var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);

        if (ratio != 0)
        {
            newHeight = (int)(originalHeight * ratio);
            newWidth = (int)(originalWidth * ratio);
        }

        using (var resizedStream = await resizedFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(resizedStream, decoder);

            encoder.BitmapTransform.InterpolationMode = BitmapInterpolationMode.Linear;
            encoder.BitmapTransform.ScaledHeight = (uint)newHeight;
            encoder.BitmapTransform.ScaledWidth = (uint)newWidth;

            await encoder.FlushAsync();
        }
}
```

Comment: How do you change it in your code? What effect do you want to implment? Please clarify your issue more clearly.

Comment: I added a code I'm using. Please help.

Comment: It seems the resizedFile's size has changed and is different from the sourceFile. What is the mean that the image metadata still shows the original image size? What do you want to change?

Comment: The original file size is e.g. 1MB (3500x2500 px) and the resized file (450x250 px) should be around 40Kb but it still says it's 1MB after resize. The dimensions are changed but not the actual size.

Comment: It is odd, I tried your code in my side, the size has changed. If I resieze the file smaller, the file really become to the comparable smaller size. Do you make sure that? What is your app target version? Could you have a try again and see the files properties again?

Comment: I looked deeper in folders and it works ok, and the size is correct. I was viewing the wrong folder. Many thanks for help!